# CakePHP: Accessing database.php values

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to retrieve values from CakePHP's config file database.php from one of my controllers.

I'm maintaining an ex-employee's code, so I'm not positive how much of this adheres to default structures. I'm hoping this is fairly straightforward, but I can't seem to Google the right info.

File: app/config/database.php

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG
{
    var $db1 =
        array('driver' => 'mysqli',
              'connect' => 'mysql_connect',
              'host' => 'localhost',
              'login' => 'username',
              'password' => 'password',
              'database' => 'schema',
              'prefix' => '');
}
```

File: app/controllers/my_controller.php

```
// here is where I need to retrieve
// the database login and password values
```

What syntax can I use here? Is it even possible to retrieve these values, or are they only accessible to the guts of the CakePHP framework?

Comment: **ebotunes** answer works just fine if you have defined some new keys and values inside the '$default' array in database.php, however, if you have created a different array in database.php as **DreadPirateShawn** has done above, you need to use **RaYell's** answer, unless you want to make a new datasource with a *connect()* method that returns true.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$fields = get_class_vars('DATABASE_CONFIG')

echo $fields['db1']['login'];
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, no tweaking necessary. Much obliged!

Comment: +1 This works, kept me from having to duplicate the settings when something in my vendors folder needed DB access.

Comment: This returns `false`. You also forgot the trailing semi-colon and I can't edit your post because the edits should be 6 characters or longer. **Whoever searches for a way to get the defined configurations (a specific one or all of them), see the post by Timothy Onggowasito as it's a more Cake-PHP way of doing this and it actually works**

Answer (score 9):

Well, I have to say the above answer is a much quicker and simpler method than what I've been using, but just for argument's sake:

```
    App::Import('ConnectionManager');
    $ds = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
    $dsc = $ds->config;

    echo $dsc['host'];
    echo $dsc['login'];
    echo $dsc['password'];
    echo $dsc['database'];
```

I guess if anything this protects your code from a change in the name of the 'DATABASE_CONFIG' class.

Comment: That's the maintainable Cake way of doing it, very nice.

Comment: I tried this one later, but I kept getting an error that the "App" class was not included. I'm positive that -should- mean something to me, but we're back to inheriting the code and admittedly not understanding the structural requirements.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post but I just found out that there is a way to list all items in the DATABASE_CONFIG class without using `get_class_vars()` function.

I think `get_class_vars()` only works on public classes anyways.

http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-ConnectionManager.html#_enumConnectionObjects

```
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
$dataSource = ConnectionManager::enumConnectionObjects();
```

Should list everything, in fact it's output is identical to @RaYell answer.

Comment: Given the similarities (App, ConnectionManager, data source), this approach looks comparable to Iain's answer. That being said, it's good to have an additional reference point.

Comment: This solution worked the best for me as it gets me all the current configurations.

Comment: All current configurations is exactly what I needed. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ds = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->config;
echo $ds['login'];
```

Comment: When providing code that solves the problem, it is best to also give at least a short explanation of how it works so that folks reading won't have to mentally parse it line by line to understand the differences.

Answer (score 0):

But from the CakePHP 2.1 and above the given solution won't work since there are some big changes from Cake version 2.x. For Cake 2.1 and above the following way should work as I tested.

```
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
$ds = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$user = $ds->config['login'];
```

There other options you may found in the following link:

[How Can I Read the DB Configuration Settings From a Cake Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895660/how-can-i-read-the-db-configuration-settings-from-a-cake-shell/10200587#10200587)