# Get database table data in a Cakephp Shell

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, console

I want to retrieve a data from the database table into a cakephp shell script.

I have tried with the below code but its not working.

Code :

```
App::import('Model', 'ModelName');
$this->ModelName = ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');
$result = $this->ModelName->find('all');
```

Error :

```
Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
```

I already search a lot in a google but I am not able to find any proper answer for it.

Please help me in this concern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Read the DB Configuration Settings From a Cake Shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895660/how-can-i-read-the-db-configuration-settings-from-a-cake-shell)

Comment: I already tried this but its not working. It occurs error this error : "Class 'ConnectionManager' not found"

Comment: I have solve "ConnectionManager not found" error but occur same error which is mentioned in my question

Comment: @Rav'sPatel Which Cake version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yehhh... I found it...

In case anyone else faces this, it's a case of PHP not having access to the mysql client libraries. Having a MySQL server on the system is not the correct fix. Fix for ubuntu (and PHP 5):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 2.x try:

```
$this->ModelName = ClassRegistry::getObject('ModelName');

if (!obj) {
    App::import('Model', 'ModelName');
    $this->ModelName = new ModelName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be configuration issue too, make sure your app/Config/database.php contains proper credentials.
Probably change

> 127.0.0.1

for

> localhost

and try.